# Finding the duplicate of strings in two lists of lists

Tags: python, duplicates

```
# Getting inputs from users
n = input()  # number of test cases

cases = []
cases1 = []

for case in range(int(n)):
    inputs = input()
    cases.append([str(x) for x in input().split()])  # n distinct space-separated strings
    cases1.append([str(y) for y in input().split()])  # n distinct space-separated strings

# finding the duplicates
for x in cases:
    total = 0
    if x in cases1:
        total += 1
        print(total, x)
    else:
        print(0)
```

What I am doing here is just finding the duplicate of list in two different lists (cases, cases1). But what I actually want is to find the duplicate of string in the two lists (cases, cases1) of lists.

This is the output of my program (the last two line)

```
2 # number of test cases
2
mouse cat
mouse cat
3
elephant monkey tiger
tiger lion elephant
1 ['mouse', 'cat']
0
```

This is the output I want (the last two line)

```
2
2
mouse cat
cat mouse
3
elephant monkey tiger
tiger lion elephant
2, mouse, cat
2, elephant, tiger
```

Can anyone please provide some insights on how to make changes to my code. I felt so messed up with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're asking for seems to be an [intersection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=intersection#frozenset.intersection) of multiple [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets):

```
n = input()
cases = []

for case in range(int(n)):
    cases.append(set(input().split()))

duplicates = set.intersection(*cases)

print(len(duplicates), *duplicates, sep=', ')
```

Or even more terse with a list comprehension:

```
n = input()

cases = [set(input().split()) for _ in range(int(n))]
duplicates = set.intersection(*cases)

print(len(duplicates), *duplicates, sep=', ')
```

Comment: List comprehension would make it better though!

Answer (score 1):

Does this work ?

```
txt1='elephant monkey tiger'
txt2='tiger lion elephant'

j=[i for i in txt1.split() if i in txt2.split()]
print(len(j),*j, sep=",")
```

> 2,elephant,tiger

You can probably incorporate the logic in your overall scheme of things

Comment: Becomes quite easier with list comprehension. However, I would suggest iterating through the smaller input (cases) to avoid any time constraints for huge datasets.

Comment: This works. But can you modify my code above? I need to get the input from the user and print out the duplicate of strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Getting inputs from users
n = input()  # number of test cases

cases = []

for case in range(int(n)):
    cases.append(input().split())
```

Executing the code above asks for use to input number of test cases. If user inputs 3(say), the for loop iterates 3 times to accept three space separate strings. For example, this was my input.

> 3
> alpha beta gamma
> gamma theta kappa
> kappa delta alpha

```
duplicates=[]
for n,i in enumerate(cases[:-1]):
    for j in cases[n+1:]:
        duplicates+=(list(set(i).intersection(set(j))))

print(len(duplicates),*duplicates, sep=",")
```

> 3,gamma,alpha,kappa